# Parser for unix output command in Java

Tags: java, parsing, unix, command

I'm trying to parse a following document in Java:

```
 Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
    /dev/mapper/appRunTest
                          950272    5840  944432    1% /
    tmpfs                1960087       1 1960086    1% /dev/shm
    /dev/sda1             128016      39  127977    1% /boot
    /dev/mapper/appPerformanceTest
                           65536      28   65508    1% /export/home
```

which is the result of a Unix command:

```
df -i
```

1. Is there any library for parsing unix comannd output?
2. In this case, I just need to pull the name of the folder, for example appPerformanceTest and value iuse%, anyone knows a good way to do it?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use a program like [awk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) for parsing output?  If you need to do something with it in Java, you can still use awk to find the information before passing it to your program.

Comment: Yes - please add more details about why you are using Java to parse CLI output instead of either using other CLI commands for CLI output or using Java to read the info that df is reading in the first place (which I'm assuming is possible with some library...)